# Pass Principal from web tier to remote EJB on different JVM

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb, remote-server, principal

After extensive search, I did not found a solution for this issue.
I am trying to move the EJB tier to a remote app server.

Web tier: a JSF webapp deployed within an .ear . The authentication is container managed trough a JDBC realm.

Business Tier: an .ear file containing an EJB module that made use of declarative security with role.

When the two resides on the same app server, which means same JVM, the principal and the role are transparently passed.

However, when I deploy the business tier .ear to a remote application server, on a different JVM, the invocation obviously stops working, with user  having not enough privileges.

The main question, is that possible to pass just the principal and role, without re authenticating the user again to the application server ?

I have read the [Propagating a Security Identity](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbyl.html#bnbyr), which brings more confusion to me especially in this paragraph "Trust between Containers":

> When an enterprise bean is designed so that either the original caller
>   identity or a designated identity is used to call a target bean, **the
>   target bean will receive the propagated identity only**. The target bean
>   will not receive any authentication data.